# Java: Capture System.err

Tags: java, error-handling

How can I capture a system.err and display a message to the user rather than have the terminal window appear?

The class that contains the line is NOT allowed to be modified. Heres the code:

Entry Class:

```
public Entry(String paramString1, String paramString2, String paramString3, String paramString4, String paramString5)
  {
    this.firstName = paramString1;
    this.lastName = paramString2;
    this.street = paramString3;
    this.town = paramString4;
    if (paramString5.matches("[A-Z]{2}[0-9]{1,2} [0-9]{1,2}[A-Z]{2}")) {
      this.postCode = paramString5;
    } else {
      System.err.printf("Bad postcode: '%s'\n", new Object[] { paramString5 });
      this.postCode = "???";
    }
  }
```

AddressBook Class:

```
public String add(Entry paramEntry)
  {
    if (paramEntry == null)
      return "Error: null entry";
    if (this.data.contains(paramEntry)) {
      return "Error: this entry already in the book";
    }
    boolean bool = this.data.add(paramEntry);
    if (bool) {
      return " entry added";
    }
    return "entry could not be added";
  }
```

Extended entry class:

```
public class Personal extends Entry
{
    private String dob;

    public Personal(String firstName, String lastName, String street, String town, String postcode, String theDOB)
    {
        super(firstName, lastName, street, town, postcode);
        dob = theDOB;
    }
```

Current call to add entry from the GUI class:

```
entry = Personal(firstName, lastName, street, town, postcode.toUpperCase(), dob);
message = addressbook.add(entry);
```

If I enter a bad postcode at present I get the terminal window stating "Bad poscode:   " it then creates an entry with ??? as the postcode. I want to be able to alert the user asking for another input without adding the entry. I dont know how to do this however without changing the Entry class (not allowed to modify either the Entry or AddressBook classes).

Comment: *"NOT allowed to be modified"*  Says who?

Comment: @AndrewThompson the classes were provided by the tutor and your not allowed to modify them in any way

Comment: I hope this is just a test application. Handling errors this way is probably the worst solution I have seen so far...

Comment: @ToniHopkins: If this is just an assignment, just check `"???".equals(postcode)` and do whatever is necessary.

Comment: Look to `System.setErr(PrintStream)`

Comment: @home not guilty. The classes have been provided to us. We cant modify them and must assume their right. From other questions I have asked it would seem they are teaching us some very bad habits including creating exceptions for user validation

Comment: @home its already added the entry by then though which means I would have to delete it. Is there no way of capturing it before the entry is added or would that mean having to change the entry class?

Comment: @ToniHopkins: from a conceptual point of view, the `AddressBook` should contain the validation logic: in your `add` method check if postcode equals `???`. If so display an error message, if not handle it according to the requirements (add to list)...

Comment: @home Do I need to extend the addressbook class then? (im not allowed to modify this either)

Comment: @ToniHopkins: then the question is whether inheritance is a way of modification :-) of course, it might work

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
public static void main(String... ignored) {
    System.setErr(new PrintStream(new OutputStream() {
        private StringBuilder line = new StringBuilder();

        @Override
        public void write(int b) throws IOException {
            if (b == '\n') {
                String s = line.toString();
                line.setLength(0);
                // TODO fill in what you want to do
                System.out.println("ERR " + s + " ERR");
            } else if (b != '\r') {
                line.append((char) b);
            }
        }
    }));

    System.err.println("Hello World");
    new Throwable("HERE").printStackTrace();
}
```

prints

```
ERR Hello World ERR
ERR java.lang.Throwable: HERE ERR
ERR     at Main.main(Main.java:24) ERR
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not do all the validation checks at `Personal` class itself when you are creating that object in first place? Make sure the only those objects having valid data are created. Solves your issue.

I would say do those checks and show him all errors in your person class itself.

Comment: hes wanting us to use error handling to handle all the validation (currently I have IF statements checking the inputs before passing the add command) So I figured is hes got that check in the entry class hes wanting us to use it somehow. Dont like how hes teaching us bad practice though.

Comment: oh why do you **assume** that I dont understand. If you handle all the data validation before creating that object on first place that will do for you.